# lmer model output interpretation

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I'm trying to interpret the `lmer` model output.
In particular, I am trying to explain 'HU mean' with pathology (which has 3 categories Healthy - HC- VSD), gender (M-F), and an interaction between these two factors.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: `HU mean` ~ 1 + Pathology + Gender + Pathology * Gender + (1 |      Region) + (1 | Name)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 2945.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6305 -0.6154  0.0023  0.5680  2.8352 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Name     (Intercept) 157.9    12.57   
 Region   (Intercept) 165.1    12.85   
 Residual             278.1    16.68   
Number of obs: 342, groups:  Name, 57; Region, 2

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           96.2544     9.5822   1.2134  10.045  0.04075 *  
PathologyVSD         -22.2175    10.5559  50.9999  -2.105  0.04026 *  
PathologyHC           -0.6786    10.5559  50.9999  -0.064  0.94899    
GenderM              -18.3179     4.2623  50.9999  -4.298 7.77e-05 ***
PathologyVSD:GenderM  37.4728    12.6951  50.9999   2.952  0.00477 ** 
PathologyHC:GenderM   23.3112    13.7261  50.9999   1.698  0.09554 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) PthVSD PthlHC GendrM PVSD:G
PatholgyVSD -0.092                            
PathologyHC -0.092  0.083                     
GenderM     -0.227  0.206  0.206              
PthlgVSD:GM  0.076 -0.831 -0.069 -0.336       
PthlgyHC:GM  0.071 -0.064 -0.769 -0.311  0.104
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation of the regression coefficients is not very different from that of a classical linear model with interaction. For this it's useful to refer to the table of the group averages.

$$
\begin{array}{l|cc}
\phantom{} & {\rm Male} & {\rm Female} \\ 
\hline
{\rm Healthy} & 77.9365& 96.2544 \\ 
{\rm VSD} & 133.7272 & 74.0369 \\ 
{\rm HC} & 119.5656 & 95.5758 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

Thus

- `PathologyVSD`: is the average `HU mean` for the females of the VSD group minus the average `HU mean` of the females of the Healthy group, here estimated to be $-22.2175 = 133.7272-96.2544$.
- `PathologyHC`: is the average `HU mean` of the females in the HC group minus the average `HU mean` of the females in the Healthy group.
- `GenderM`: is the average `HU mean` for Males minus the average `HU mean` for females all in the Healthy group.
- `PathologyVSD:GenderM` is the average `HU mean` of Males belonging to the VSD group minus the average `HU mean` of females in the Healthy group.
- `PathologyHC:GenderM` is the average `HU mean` of Males belonging to the HC group minus the average `HU mean` of females in the Healthy group.