# Interpreting contrasts in lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interpretation

I would like to make sure whether I’m interpreting the results of the lmer model I generated in the right way. The model is:

`lmer(distress ~ cond*group +  (1|subject), data = data)`

Condition has two levels (S1 and S2, S1 is the reference), group has 2 levels (A and B, B is the reference)

1. Would the coefficient of the three way interaction condS2:groupA indicate that **the difference** of S2 vs S1 is larger in in group A vs group B?
2. Maybe this is a stupid question but, can this also not be tested with a simple regression with a predictor group and the difference scores (S2-S1) as the DV? Would it be inappropriate because of the disregard of the random effects?
3. If I want to test whether conditions differ, within group A and within group B, do I run two different lmers for two groups seperately?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check my answer to a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/599259/56940)

Comment: thank you for your very fast feedback, utobi. I was wondering, if I wanted to test whether the difference of S1 vs S2 is larger/smaller in Group A vs B, should I then create a different model here or would your interprations under the other post mean essentially the same thing?